# Failed to load ApplicationContext with OAuth2 resource server issuer URI when running @WebMvcTest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

My Spring Boot application defines an OAuth2 resource server like this in the `application.yml`:

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: ${AUTH_SERVER_METADATA_URL:http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo}
```

This works fine when actually running the application.

When, however, running tests with`@WebMvcTest` and `MockMvc` to test a `@RestController` class, then the test fails with the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
...
...
I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo/.well-known/openid-configuration": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

The message is pretty clear in its root cause, but I don't know how I could "mock" the connection for sliced tests without spinning up a real Keycloak or WireMock server.

Running the same test with my development Keycloak server running in the background works fine.

Comment: When running integration tests, configure Spring Security to [read the public key from the class path](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-decoder-public-key-boot) instead of trying to get it from the authorization server.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding `@MockBean JwtDecoder` to your unit-tests class properties?

You'll next probably need to populate your security-context with `JwtAuthenticationToken` instances satisfying your security rules.

To achieve that, you might either use:

- `@WithMockJwtAuth` from https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons
- mockMvc.perform(get(...).with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.jwt()...)) from spring-security-test

Both in action:

```java
@WebMvcTest(GreetingController.class)
@Import(SampleApi.WebSecurityConfig.class)
class GreetingControllerAnnotatedTest {

    @MockBean JwtDecoder jwtDecoder;

    @Autowired
    MockMvc api;

    @Test
    @WithMockJwtAuth(authorities = "ROLE_AUTHORIZED_PERSONNEL", claims = @OpenIdClaims(sub = "Ch4mpy", preferredUsername = "Tonton Pirate"))
    void greetWithAnnotation() throws Exception {
        api.perform(get("/greet")).andExpect(content().string("Hello Ch4mpy! You are granted with [ROLE_AUTHORIZED_PERSONNEL]."));
    }

    @Test
    void greetWithPostProcessor() throws Exception {
        api.perform(get("/greet").with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.jwt()
                .authorities(List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_AUTHORIZED_PERSONNEL"))).jwt(jwt -> {
                    jwt.subject("Ch4mpy");
                    jwt.claims(claims -> claims.put(StandardClaimNames.PREFERRED_USERNAME, "Tonton Pirate"));
                }))).andExpect(content().string("Hello Ch4mpy! You are granted with [ROLE_AUTHORIZED_PERSONNEL]."));
    }
}
```

Complete sample [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/webmvc-jwtauthenticationtoken)